# Code to display all prime numbers not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, primes

I'm trying to display all the prime numbers up to 10 and it isn't working. Can you see what I did wrong?

```
function findPrimeNumbers() {
    var count = 10,
        primes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        if (count / i === 1 || count) primes.push(i);
        else continue;
        count -= 1;
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = primes.length; i < len; i++) return primes[i];
}

console.log(findPrimeNumbers());
```

It only returns 0 in the console.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: It only returns 0. Not all prime numbers up to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (var i = 0, len = primes.length; i < len; i++) return primes[i];`

Here you are return just the first element of the array. I think you meant something like this

```
var retstr = "";
for (var i = 0, len = primes.length; i < len; i++)
{
    //To improve str format
    if(i == len-1)
        retstr += primes[i];
    else
        retstr += primes[i] + ", ";
}

return retstr;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's about the simplest way to generate primes.  Note that there are more efficient methods, but they are harder to understand.

```
function findPrimeNumbers (count) {
    var primes              = [];

    for (var J = 2;  J <= count;  J++) {
        var possPrime       = true;

        for (var K = 2, factorLim = Math.sqrt (J);  K <= factorLim;  K++) {
            if (J % K == 0) {
                possPrime   = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (possPrime)
            primes.push (J);
    }
    return primes;
}

console.log (findPrimeNumbers (10) );
```

This yields all the primes <= 10:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
```

[See Wikipedia for an explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes#Trial_division).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count / i === 1 || count / i === count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say *how* it's not working, but the first thing that comes to my attention is that you're incrementing **i**, while at the same time decrementing **count**, so **i** will never get all the way to 10.

Also, **count / i** will cause a divide-by-zero error on the first iteration as it's written (unless Javascript magically handles that case in some way I'm not familiar with).

Then you "loop" through your return values--but you can only return *once* from a function, so of course you're only going to return the first value.

Answer (score 0):

And you are returning from the function in the last for loop. Remove that for loop, just return the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function PrimeCheck(n){      //function to check prime number
 for(i=2;i<n;i++){
  if(n%i==0){
   return false
  }
}
return true;
}
 function print(x){                   //function to print prime numbers
var primeArray=[];
for(j=2;j<x;j++){
if(PrimeCheck(j)==true){             
  primeArray.push(j);
}
}
 console.log(primeArray);
}
print(10);                          //[2,3,5,7]
```